# regex object not working like simple regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Having trouble converting a simple regex to a regex object... using jquery replace.

```
var st =  "saturate(0.2)"

// this is working
alert(st.replace(/saturate\(.*?\)/, "saturate(0.5)")) 

// so why is this not working exactly the same?
var st =  "saturate(0.2)"
var regex = new RegExp("saturate\(.*?\)", "")
alert(st.replace(regex, "saturate(0.5)"))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y6wGw/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` characters inside a string literal:

```
var regex = new RegExp("saturate\\(.*?\\)", "")
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/y6wGw/1/)